# COM Порт в python: как ждать данные, не нагружая CPU

Tags: python, serial, com-порт

Есть программа, которая принимает данные из COM порта. Возникла проблема, как заставить программу ждать данные и не выполняться дальше?

При использовании бесконечного цикла while, программа нагружает ЦП до 50%.

```
forchar = 0
idcom = []

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = 'COM2',\
    baudrate=2400,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
    timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
count=1

while True:
    for line in ser.readline():
        forchar = forchar + 1
        idcom.append(line)
    if forchar >= 13:
        break
```

Comment: Небольшая поправка. Ваша программа не "нагружает ЦП до 50%", а "нагружает 1 ядро на 100%".

Comment: вариант с while не подходит , та как проц в потоке занят циклом опроса . надо прерывение по приёму 1 символа , и именно от аппаратного прерывания ,

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развёрнутый ответ.  "занят циклом опроса " - опроса чего? "надо прерывание по приёму 1 символа" - а как, вы можете добавить код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас порт настроен на неблокирующее чтение, так как установлен `timeout=0`, Либо уберите эту опцию, либо напишите `timeout=None`, тогда порт у вас будет ждать данные, до тех пор пока они не появятся.

Если же вам все таки нужно неблокирующее соединение, то в цикл `while` надо добавить небольшую задержку `time.sleep`, тогда нагрузка процессора уйдет.

Answer (score 1):

Еще есть такая конструкция:

```
    while True:
        while ser.inWaiting() == 0:
            pass
        #необходимая работа с данными...
```

Тут выполняется проверка на наличие данных в очереди порта. Такой способ ожидания, ЦП не нагружает совсем.

Comment: `inWaiting()` равнозначен `queue.qsize()`, что не блокирует поток надолго. Цикл выглядит как busy loop.

Answer (score 0):

Так понятнее

```
        while ser.inWaiting():
             data = ser.read()
```

пока в порте нет данных чтение не выполняетса

Comment: если в порте нет данных, то цикл просто сразу завершается.

Answer (score 0):

допустим

```
def recCode(data):#  и поехали проверять по условиям - например
    if data == (b'\x05sRR\r\n')
        print(u'я получил сообщение ')


while True:
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:# даже если мы поставим без условия
    data = ser.readline()
    recCode(data)
```

при таком построении алгоритма `while True` будет выполнятся постоянно и `recCode(data)` будет вызываться при приёме каждого символа (байта) в порт, а если 1 количество байтов в пакете не известно(работа по стартовому и конечному символу) или 2  надо ещё обслуживать графический интерфейс и в добавок 3 отправлять данные (сообщения ) в порт , то некоторые символы (принимаемые ) могут потеряться , да и программа (не зависимо сколько ядер у процессора ) будет занята только этим , а если надо 2 порта обслуживать ?

в ассемблере (avr контроллеры), в VB6(x86 и 64), есть возможность применения аппаратных прерываний , т е событие (приём символа портом ) может (при правильной настройке аппаратного узла контроллера или машины), остановить выполнение (или перенаправить поток команд) основного тела программы , выполнить подпрограмму (прерывание) приёма одного символа с возможностью формирования строки по стартовым и конечным символам (`\х05` и `\r\n`) и после приёма конечного символа непосредственно в подпрограмме (если условий мало ) обработать - изменив переменные или, выставить флаг готовности принятого сообщения для основной программы , или изменив глобальную переменную для других процессов.

тогда `while True` может заниматься (допустим ) проверкой флагов готовности сообщения одного , второго , н-ого порта , обновлением процессов графической оболочки типа root=Tk() ..(графические элементы ) , и в место root.vfinloop() использовать   root.update(), тк как графические интерфейсы управления достаточно медленные процессы